# Words coming up in individual lines when parsing csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, parsing, text-parsing

I am trying to parse a csv file in java and am running in to a problem. When I try to split the csv up like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nameOfFile = "KingstonNorthWard2016Distribution.csv";
    File file = new File(nameOfFile);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
        }
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My console returns this:

```
[Distribution]
[Report]
[]
[Print]
[Date/Time:]
[31/10/2016]
[07:27:10PM]
[Bayside]
[City]
[Council]
[2016]
```

Despite my csv looking like this:

```
Distribution Report                               ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Print Date/Time: 31/10/2016 07:27:10PM,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Bayside City Council 2016,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Central Ward,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

What I can't understand is why my console doesn't look like this:

```
[Distribution report]
[Print Date/Time: 31/10/2016 07:27:10PM]
[Bayside City Council 2016]
[Central Ward]
```

If anyone could help that would by great. For extra points, the csv later goes on to list names like "Smith, John" so bear that in mind if my split is in need of change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, that CSV is a very strange format, there shouldn't be any need for so many commas in a group. See here for what a CSV file should look like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: Unless this is just a programming exercise, consider using one of the several excellent open source CSV parsing libraries.

Comment: @AndrewB The csv file has a lot more used columns further down, these are just the headings at the top of the spreadsheet

Comment: There are some complex subtleties to parsing CSV format successfully.  Do not write your own parser, use one of the existing libraries to do the parsing for you.  It will handle conditions like quoted strings, escaped characters and embedded commas within a quoted field.

Comment: Even if there are other columns, that is not the format of CSV, one comma is needed as a separator, more than one will leave you with many elements that are empty.

Comment: That's the intention @AndrewB . As I said the CSV gets hectic later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasNext` and `next` iterate over words, you want `hasNextLine` and `nextLine`.

As for the fields which contain your delimiter, we'd have to look at a sample from your dataset to try and see if there is a rule we can define which shows a delimiter can be ignored by `split`.